# Unsupported HDF5 version

Tags: hdf5, pytables

Trying to install Pytables, and I've installed almost all dependencies:
However, when I'm trying to install pytables:

```
* Found numpy 1.7.0b1 package installed.
* Found numexpr 2.0.1 package installed.
* Found Cython 0.16 package installed.
* Found HDF5 headers at ``/home/xug/pytables/hdf5/include``, library at ``/home/xug/pytables/hdf5/lib``.
.. ERROR:: Unsupported HDF5 version!
```

What does "unsupported HDF5 version" mean?

Comment: Problem solved, as HDF-1.8.4 at least is required by Pytables.

Comment: Glad you solved it! It would be nice if you could rewrite this comment as a regular answer and mark it as accepted (so other people immediately know this is a solved problem).

Answer (score 2):

Although the author of the question has answered it in the comment, I think it is appropriate to have the (perhaps a bit more verbose) answer here too.

As mentioned, the problem is caused by a wrong (or lacking) systemwide version of HDF5 libraries. In my case, I solved it by compiling a newer version and installing it locally:

```
$ wget http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/hdf5-1.8.11.tar.bz2
$ tar xjvf hdf5-1.8.11.tar.bz2
$ cd hdf5-1.8.11
$ configure --prefix=~/localroot
$ make -j 8
$ make install
```

It is then necessary to specify the path to this local installation before compiling package:

```
$ export HDF5_DIR=~/localroot
$ pip install tables
```

Finally, `~/localroot/lib` must be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for PyTables to work, so I added the line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/localroot/lib
```

to `~/.bashrc`